# Is there a graph with extroversion-introversion score on one axis and IQ on the other?

Tags: iq, extraversion, introversion, big-five

I can't find one on Google Images.

Answer (score 4):

Extraversion and IQ typically have zero correlation. In Bates and Rock (2004),we suggested that if the arousal value of the testing environment varies, this might induce a modest correlation with IQ (introverts doing best in silences, ambiverts with some noicse, and extraverts performing best under fairly loud white noise background. More basic measures like [inspection time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspection_time) were unaffected.

[image: Extraversion*Arousal interaction effect on IQ scores]

Based on some followup queries, here's a graph of Extraversion against IQ-score in 597 adults from a normative sample in the United States: The [MIDUS](http://www.midus.wisc.edu).

The plot shows the raw data points, and also a loess best fit curve: no relationship, even at the extremes.

[image]

Comment: But how can that be? 75% of people above a certain IQ are introverted and there are so many stupid extroverts in the world. Sociability peaks at about 85 IQ I've heard. Where are the people that balance these people out? This doesn't seem to be a case of simple linear tendency.

Comment: What's the correlation with people below 70 IQ excluded? (the mentally challenged)

Comment: It's not the case that "75% of people above a certain IQ are introverted". I can post some data if people would find it helpful, but the population correlation is near zero. It's also not the case that extraverts are "stupid", nor that sociability peaks at about 85. Regarding what would happen excluding people with IQ<70. Not a lot. Barely 2% of the population in a country like, say, Canada, score that low or lower..

Comment: Well I've found this: (bottom of page 3) http://eric.ed.gov/?id=ED428473 and this http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1300/J274v18n03_08 So, people over 130 are a small part of the population too. If it quickly becomes introverted very roughly there then the correlation could still be near zero. Isn't a symmetric V a zero correlation too? Not that that's my proposed shape, I have no idea what the graph would look like. Yes, very high IQ extroverts exist.

Comment: (continued) But I find equal I:E percent distributions from Einstein to "retard" hard to believe. Are you saying that it'd look like random dots of subjects covering the whole square? (and when I called some of the world's extroverts "stupid", I should've said low IQ, obviously their social skills could be genius level). Also, if you're an extrovert, you shouldn't feel bad if this is true, if that's the case then high social skills people with advanced degrees would be uncommonly able and get paid more.

Comment: Wouldn't Bates and Rock (2004) suggest that the average MIDUS IQ test was done in medium arousal conditions? Is that known? This masters thesis from Georgia Tech seems to agree with you but shows about -0.25 correlation w/ extroversion for general knowledge and pretty much any subfield under the sun: https://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/9454/wolf_mark_b_200405_ms.pdf

Comment: (continued) Maybe they can stand the lack of loud white noise of most tests long enough to compete on IQ tests but can't keep it up long enough to use the IQ to learn much? (cause they're too busy feeding their strange socializing and excitement drives and their effort grows their social knowledge instead?). Also, reading 24/7 like some introv. students do bores extros cause they need stimulating activities (like nights out and bungee jumping).

Comment: I wouldn't say the MIDUS data is completely inconsistent with that study of hundreds of gifted children, either. There's hardly anyone above 137.5 on that chart and allegedly introverted highly gifted children (160+) outnumber extroverted by 3 to 1 (but only 3 to 2 of gifted children). More studies are needed.